# Maven plug-in errors in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I got the following Maven plug-in error in pom.xml. Any suggestion on how to fix it? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message looks like having problems with accessing Maven central? Firewall / proxy issue...

Comment: but other maven project works fine ...

Comment: Hm..you see the transfer errors in the error message? There is a transfer error..so what could it be? You might have changed your code/pom file etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

Without the effective pom to observe, it looks like `java.version` isn't specified *as one of your `<properties/>`*.  Are you certain that you have a valid value for that?

On a *nix like box you might

```
mvn -U help:effective-pom|grep java.version
```

and see if you get any results (should be something like `<java.version>1.7</java.version>`